# How do I calculate the area of a contoured image in OpenCV4?

Tags: python, image, opencv, contour, area

I have a question regarding the calculation of a contoured area in OpenCV 4. Im using the following code to calculate the area of my contour:

```
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(closing, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnts1,_ = cv2.findContours(gray2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
de1=cv2.drawContours(closing, cnts1, -1, (0, 0, 255), thickness=1)
ar = cv2.contourArea(cnts1)
#ar = cv2.contourArea(cnts1[0])
```

When I try to launch the code I always get the error message: `TypeError: Expected Ptr <cv::UMat> for argument 'contour'`.
When I change the line `ar = cv2.contourArea(cnts1)` for `ar = cv2.contourArea(cnts1[0])` the code is working but the result of `ar` is `0`. And thats fine because `cnts1[0]` is just one point of the contour line.
But how do I get the area of the whole contoured part of the picture ? It seems as if the function `cv2.contourArea()` just accepts single points as input.

Is there something very obvious I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance :).

Cheers

EDIT:
updated code to loop over contours

```
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(closing, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnts1,_ = cv2.findContours(gray2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
de1=cv2.drawContours(closing, cnts1, -1, (0, 0, 255), thickness=1)
                    
r=len(cnts1)
r1=[]

for i in range(1,r):
   ar1 = cv2.contourArea(cnts1[i])
   r1.append(ar1)
print(r1)
ar = cv2.contourArea(cnts1[0])
print(ar)
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5678.5]
0.0
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: You have many contours. You need to loop over each contour and then get its area using  cv2.contourArea

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Looping over all values of  `cnts1` gives me a list full of the same value, `[5707.0, 5707.0, 5707.0, 5707.0, 5707.0]` for example. No idea what's 
the problem ^^. I also don't understand why looping actually gives me values for the contour area but calculating one contour value of `cnts1` always returns `0`.

Comment: Edit your question with your new code

Comment: Just edited the code :)

Comment: Can you show your result of drawContours? Try thresholding your  grayscale image so that the regions you want for contours is white on black background.

Comment: yeah, just uploaded it, do you have any Idea where the zeroes are coming from ?
Theres a little red dot in the lower left part of the picture, but the zeroes are showing up too when it isn't there

Comment: Just a guess, but if you zoom in, you will see that you have lots of 1 pixel white regions in the antennae and legs. So those could be giving that, thought I would have expected 1 not 0. You could filter on area and throw those out. Or you can use a small morphology close filter to close up the gaps, then try again.

Comment: yes, there have to be some small regions, I also expected 1x1 pixels to produce the value 1, but ok, maybe not. I'll just create a new list which thresholds the values of list r1. Thank you :) !